# reactjs -- how to put object data cleanly into a url - but also how to access those parameters?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react js application - and I need to create a redirect - that will go to a url - with a bunch of params -- an id, then multiple terms - key/value pair type approach

data

id = 23
terms = {"budget": "how does it look now", "gender": "male", "age": 32}

so the url will look something like this
partnerspage?id=23&terms[budget]=how does it look now&terms[gender]=male&terms[age]=32

-- and then on this partners page in the component did mount

I want to gain access to this data -- so - I'm using routing and on some pages I have the routing using forward slash  activate/{token} --

would the listener for these params be something like

console.log("params", this.props.location.search)? -- how would I get the data from the url?

Comment: are you using `react-router` for routing? If yes you can wrap your component with `withRouter` hoc or in functional component you can use, `useLocation` hook, and get access to the `location.search`. then you might need to parse the string either using a library like [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) or [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: I'm not using hooks for this project - but yes I got withRouter on -- you got a js sandbox demo of what you mean

Comment: I'm not even sure how I should make the url look -- cause the service api is a bit still draft

Comment: You can try `this.props.match.params.id` to get `id` or other variables. With hooks `useParams()` will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a sandbox for the solution i mentioned in the comment, check it out, lmk if there is an issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-framework-w0grj?file=/src/Main.js

Comment: no I need to create the string first and use it like a redirect -- so partners?id=2&terms=..... - how would I write the object here

Comment: @TheOldCounty  that is also possible, i updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-framework-w0grj?file=/src/Main.js:27-95) , just the general way to do it, you will need to make use of the same principle for your implementation.

Comment: thank you I got access to it -- what if you wanted to hash the url or something so it wasn't sending over an object -- and then unhash it on the other end -- not an md5 I guess - but something you could send and not get lost in translation or keeping the url shorter

Comment: @TheOldCounty yeah you could try that, but i don't think it will shorten the url significantly, if you want to shorten the url, you will have to have a mapping in for a key in url in local storage, where you can retrieve using the key in url.

Comment: I think they didn't want to necessarily show a big object in the url

Comment: yes then follow the localStorage approach, with a dynamically generated id, something like a GUID or sth, and store the object in localStorage using that key. retrieve when necessary.  Also please upvote if you found it helpful.

Comment: but then - it may be something you would want to share?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223543/discussion-between-anuja-and-the-old-county).

Comment: I don't really have much else to say about it -- if it could be md5 and then reversed - but - at the moment its got an object in the url - I'm able to pick it up and work with it - so its ok for now